# Find Region Boundaries in Marked Object in OpenCV for Python

Tags: python, opencv, contour, boundary

I'm looking to find the region boundaries (contour) of a quadrilateral in an image. I know the location of one point within the region, but I don't know much a priori about the color/size properties of the region. All I know is that there will be a strong edge surrounding the entire region and that it's a quadrilateral.

Currently, I'm using a thresholding algorithm to find areas close in intensity/color to the starting point, and then finding the largest resulting contour that contains the reference point. However, there can be a gradual change in intensity/color over the region, which can cause this to fail. Below is a sample image as well as a snippet of my code using this method. It works okay with the first image, but not the second.

```
I = imread('bluerect.jpg') # Read image
reference_marker = np.array([460,950]) # Manually mark note
I_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(I, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Set bounds based on color of reference point
hsv_value = I_hsv[reference_marker[0],reference_marker[1],:]
lower = np.array([hsv_value[0]-8,hsv_value[1]-hsv_value[1]*.3, hsv_value[2]-hsv_value[2]*.7])
upper = np.array([hsv_value[0]+8,hsv_value[1]+hsv_value[1]*.3, hsv_value[2]+hsv_value[2]*.7])
mask = cv2.inRange(I_hsv, lower, upper) # Find what's in that range

# Fill holes in mask with morphological close
closed_mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, np.ones((5,5),np.uint8))

# Find the contour with the maximum area that contains marker
ret, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closed_mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for target in sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse=True):
    bb = cv2.boundingRect(target)
    if (bb[0] < center[0] < bb[0]+bb[2]) & (bb[1] < center[1] < bb[1] + bb[3]):
        break
```

[image: Image 1 - Blue Rectangle]
[image: Image 2 - White Rectangle]

I think the best approach would be to "fill out" from the reference point until I hit a strong, contiguous boundary... something like a watershed algorithm? Anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: This needs a sample input image along with a [mcve] showing what you already have.

Comment: Okay added. I'm not necessarily looking for complete code or anything, maybe just an algorithm that might work. Thanks!

Comment: You may try with `watershed`, `mean-shift` and `flood-fill` techniques